# What is the REST endpoint for specific case (need a boolean only)

Tags: rest, web-services, api

Let say we have a micro-service called User and another one called Bill (not Gates).

I want to delete a User but first I need to check if he has bills or not linked to him.

For the moment I call Bill to get all the bills of that User. If empty I can delete him, if not I do nothing.
This method is fine since I don't have to modify the Bill micro-service. But if a User has 10000 bills, the User micro-service will probably wait some times to get all the bills and count them.

What would be the HTTP REST call to know if User has Bills?